# How can I retrieve data through a serial terminal without corrupting its fundamental value in GNU ARM embedded?

Tags: c++, casting, arm, gnu

I'm wondering if anyone can help me spot the problem here...

In my C++ embedded program for an STM32L, I'm trying to retrieve a binary data file stored on an SD card over a serial connection via a CLI (or terminal, or whatever will work). So far, I can read the data file just fine using the FatFs f_read function. It's contents are being stored in the f_read buffer, which I can verify in debug mode.

However, the problem is that the RTOS I'm using requires outgoing data to be in the const char* form, so I'm forced to somehow get the elements into that type. So far I've been doing this by casting, however, depending on which type I use as a an f_read buffer, this either causes nothing to be printed or changes the its fundamental hex value when it's transferred over the serial connection to the CLI on my CPU.

Here's the operative part of my code. In this instance I'm storing the buffer data as uint16_t, but I've tried many other types (char, BYTE, char*), none of which manage to get the data to the other side without being corrupted.

```
FRESULT res;
FIL fsrc;
uint16_t buffer[512];
uint16_t bw = 0;

res = f_open(&fsrc, "zurn.dat", FA_READ | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS);  

res = f_read(&fsrc, buffer, sizeof buffer, &bw);                                      

//just printing the first few elements to see if it works
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
     CLI_printMessage(ZString((const char*)buffer[i])); 
}

f_close(&fsrc);
```

I must emphasize that its the fundamental hex values that I'm trying to transfer. A user has already kindly showed me how to get the ASCII representation of the hex values to go through (which I may have to resort to in the end), however, it'd be more useful for me if there's a way to get maintain the hex values themselves rather.

To further clarify, as an example: the first few characters of the data file look like this in ASCII: Èì‰Jà­©í, and this in Hex: ecc8 8903 e04a a9ad. This is what I need on the other side, rather than this in ASCII: ecc8 8903 e04a a9ad, which is this in hex: 6563 6338 2038 3930 3320 6530 3461 2061 3961 64.

**Some further thoughts:**
I realize the problem is likely with the casting. For starters, it gives me the warning "cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]". I understand this is because in C++ pointers default to 16 bits, hence the uint16_t type for my buffer.

I've also tried copying the data stored in the buffer to another variable, and casting that. In most circumstances, this shows the proper hex values at the debug level, but with lots of ASCII junk attached to it, of which I have no explanation for. I've also tried reducing my buffer array size to a mere 8 elements, still no difference.

The answer may also be specific to my RTOS, which has many special types made for it that I don't fully understand, though its mostly based on FreeRTOS. If you haven't noticed I'm not a very experienced programmer...

Also, I'm using the Eclipse IDE and the GNU Arm Build Tools.

Comment: I'm guessing that your CLI is ascii, but your `buffer` is `uint16_t`, then you need to print the elements as integers in decimal, binary or hex as makes most sense to you.

Comment: Hmm not sure I fully understand... my RTOS requires that I print each element as a const char*, how to could I print them as hex? Note: I don't have access to regular C++ libraries such as iostream.

Comment: This is just what I demonstrated below.  You can not print 'binary'  generally your CLI will use some [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) and it is only a 'char' or 8 bits.  Your sample is 16bits.  A direct map 16bits to 2 bytes gives two characters and they may not print.  As well, the `CLI_printMessage` probably wants the last byte to be zero or the NUL character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting will not solve the issue and perhaps you have illustrated why casting is bad.

---

You need a function like something like this,

```
/* four 'nibbles' (nibble = 4 bits = one hex) is 16 bits. */
void int16ToString(char *buf[4], uint16_t val)
{
   static const char *lookup = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   buf[3] = lookup[val & 0xf]; /* write backwards or you need a copy of val */
   val = val >> 4;
   buf[2] = lookup[val & 0xf];
   val = val >> 4;
   buf[1] = lookup[val & 0xf];
   val = val >> 4;
   buf[0] = lookup[val & 0xf];
}
```

There are various functions in the C library, etc which do similar things.  Obviously the routine needs a buffer of 4 bytes and it is not null terminated by the routine.  It is just to demonstrate what needs to happen.  `sprintf`, `snprint`, etc will be useful to look at as well as `itoa`, etc.

---

Why do you need a function like that?  Because there are two sides to the conversation and they can (and probably do [interpret things differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean)).  Generally you can transfer the lower ascii characters without effect.  For example 'XON' is a flow control character that can be embedded in a data stream.

If you are to transmit the binary data via the CLI you need to 'clean it' and then you need code on the other side of the CLI uart to undo that. You can just send hex and then convert back to binary. There are more efficient ways to do this such as [zmodem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) and [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) if the data is large or the link (CLI uart) is not reliable.  A simple [`itoa()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) with a  [hexdump](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sektion=1) conversion on another host will transfer the binary which is suitable for a debugging transfer.

Comment: I think I've worded my question poorly... itoa works just fine getting the ASCII representations of the hex values to print (which I thank you for directing me towards), however it's the hex values themselves I need to maintain during the transfer, the ASCII representations don't actually matter. I'll (heavily) edit my question to reflect this..

Comment: That's actually what I've settled on... I've discovered an io function deep within my RTOS that will allow me to print the itoa() hexdump as a solid block (the preexisting one was printing one line at a time). A remarkably simple solution for something I've been struggling with for so long... thanks a lot for your input, it was very useful.

Comment: If it is smaller binary data, you should transfer a few times (3-5) and verify that they are all the same.  It is quite common for one side to drop a character, etc.  I guess not everybody has lived through a time of BBSs. :-)

Comment: Actually, I'm just realizing f_read is skipping over the leading zeros. New problems! (Also, for the record, they're going to be very large files)

Comment: That is a different layer though.  Something in your OS.  Just remember that even if there is just a "NULL cable" between things you will still occasionally get data corruption.  I had an HSDPA module inside a battery powered case connected on the PCB and the 'UART' coms would sometimes get garbled characters (1 in a million, etc).  If you get the transfer right and try to analyse the FAT data, double check an error is **NOT** due to the data transfer.  It would be worse with straight binary; if you see non-hex characters there is probably garbled characters.

Comment: "Something in your OS" as in my RTOS? I can see the zeros are being dropped when I check the f_read buffer contents in debug mode. I've been considering adding some code to bit shift and add a zero to any element with only 15 bits.

Comment: That is not 'f_read is skipping over the leading zeros' as you said.  You could pad/start your buffer with 0xffff and then 'f_read' to buffer[1].  Then you need to skip the first 'ffff' or just remove it with an editor.

Comment: UPDATE: I've actually abandoned this entire process, just imported the data decoding program directly into my embedded system. Seems to work fine. Still, lots of good info on this thread thanks to @artless noise